# Stokes Question (non-conservative vector field but 0 flux as answer?)

Tags: vector-fields, stokes-theorem

I have a Stokes question.

> $C$ is a curve created by intersection of a cylinder $x^2+y^2=9$ and a plane $z=1+y-2x$. The curve is clockwise when viewed from the positive $z$-axis. The vector function is $$F(x,y,z)=\langle 4z,-2y,2y\rangle.$$

I have done this a few times and keep getting $0$. The curl $F$  is not equal to zero, so this is a non-conservative vector field.

I am wondering how I can have flux $= 0$ here, when the vector field is non-conservative? Perhaps I did something wrong?

Comment: It is certainly possible for there to exist some closed curve $C$ and a non$-$ conservative vector field $F$ such that $\oint_{C}F\cdot dr=0$. However, if $\oint_CF\cdot dr=0$ for *any* closed curve $C$, then $F$ must be conservative.

Comment: So if I calculate Curl F=0, the question is basically done, the final answer must be 0. But, vice versa could occur, Curl F not equal to 0, but my Flux = 0?

Comment: You can definitely get zero out of integrating something that isn't identically zero. This is basically a continuum version of $1 + (-1)=0$.